# Creating and consuming a custom image in Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to create a Docker image that stores some installs that we can use in our other images using Docker Desktop.  The image is called MyTools and it builds successfully and I can see it in the dashboard when I run `docker-compose up -d`, however I'm getting an issue when I try to pass it as a build arg to another image. I'm getting the following error:

> Status: pull access denied for lvtools, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1

I have found that if I re-run `docker-compose up` without removing the tools image it works fine.  Can I do this in one compose file? I presume it can't find it but I don't understand why that would be. Below is my `docker-compose` file which contains both the image definitions.

This is my tools definition:

```
tools:
 image: mytools
 build:
  context: ./docker/build/mytools
  args:
    BASE_IMAGE: ${SOLUTION_BASE_IMAGE}
```

This is the service that I would like to pass in the mytools image to

```
cm:
image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xm1-cm:${VERSION:-latest}
build:
  context: ./docker/build/cm
  args:
    MY_TOOLS: mytools
```

Comment: Do you have .env file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by setting a depends_on from the CM service to the tools solved the problem.  I also noticed that the image gets tagged with the registry address which needs to be included when passing it in to the build args

e.g
MY_TOOLS: mytools

should be

MY_TOOLS: address of registry/mytools